# using variable in linq group by clause

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say that i have a table with multiple columns (student, teacher, subject, marks) and I want to compare each of these column to another table with same columns (with sum(marks)).

I have the following method with column name as an argument, which is then used in group by clause.

```
public List<AllMarks> RIMarks(string filter)
{
  var MarkTable = from p in MainDB.classTable
                  let fil = filter
                  group p by new { fil } into g
                  select new AllMarks
                  {
                    Column = g.Key.fil,
                    Marks = g.Sum(f => f.Mark)
                  };

  List<AllMarks> lstRI = MarkTable.ToList();
  return lstRI;
}

public void Test()
{
  var filter = new string[] {"Student", "Teacher", "Subject"}
  foreach (f in filter) 
  {
    // Call RIMarks(f) and do something
  }
}
```

I have number of distinct students in my table, however with this method, what I get is just a single row with sum(marks(all students) for the first filter criteria (which is Student) and its not actually grouping by the student.

How do I use local variable in linq groupby clause ?

Update:
Sample DB:

```
Student    Teacher    Subject    Marks
stu1       teac1      sub1       23
stu1       teac1      sub1       45
stu2       teac2      sub2       34
```

Comment: It seems to me that you're grouping by **the strings** passed as `filter` argument, not by specified record's field. Actually your function does not care what is in 'filter' string, it will always sum all the rows. Try pass something like `"bananas"` as filter criteria into your function.

Comment: Exactly. It just create a new column with the filter criteria and not actually use that to group. So my output shows only one record like Student - 2433243434 whereas there are actually 100 unique students under Student column.

Comment: Can you show what `MainDB.classTable`'s elements look like?

Comment: added the sample data. My intention is, I have different table which shares some similar columns among them. I jus want to check whether sum(marks) are same with different column name when I use this method in different table.

Comment: What do you *actually* want to group on?  If you group on a constant, you will, by definition, get one group.  If you want groups of "something" you need to define what "something" is.  If you want groups of students, you need to group on some identifying quality of what it means to be "a student".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to group by the name of a particular property of some data object you have. 
You want to reflect the property of the field you want then group by that field's values. 
You can't just provide the name because the filter wont work and it'll just group the whole collection.

Test this out in LinqPad.

What you have are the marks being summed on the grouping, not sure if you wanted the average but

what you have here should lead you to getting the average.

```
void Main()
{
    var mySchool = new List<School>{
    new School{Student = "Student A", Teacher = "Teacher A", Subject = "Math", Marks = 80},
    new School{Student = "Student B", Teacher = "Teacher A", Subject = "Math", Marks = 65},
    new School{Student = "Student C", Teacher = "Teacher A", Subject = "Math", Marks = 95},
    new School{Student = "Student A", Teacher = "Teacher B", Subject = "History", Marks = 80},
    new School{Student = "Student B", Teacher = "Teacher B", Subject = "History", Marks = 100},
    };

    GroupByFilter("Student", mySchool);
    GroupByFilter("Teacher", mySchool);
    GroupByFilter("Subject", mySchool);
}

public void GroupByFilter(string filter, List<School> school)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = typeof(School).GetProperties()
                                  .Where(x => x.Name == filter)
                                  .First();

    var grouping = from s in school
                   group s by new {filter = prop.GetValue(s)} into gr
                   select new {
                    Filter = gr.Key.filter,
                    Marks = gr.Sum(x => x.Marks)
                   };
    grouping.Dump(); // this is linqpad specific
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class School{
    public string Student {get;set;}
    public string Teacher {get;set;}
    public string Subject {get;set;}
    public int Marks {get;set;}
}
```

### Results

Group By Student

Filter  Marks

Student A 160

Student B 165

Student C 95

---

Group By Teacher
Filter  Marks

Teacher A 240

Teacher B 180

---

Group By Subject
Filter  Marks

Math 240

History 180

Comment: My problem with this code is how do I now get the group collection?  The grouping is a void that returns nothing so I can't assign GroupByFilter to anything.  How do I use the new collection?

Answer (score 0):

please try below code.

```
public List<AllMarks> RIMarks(string filter)
{
if (filter == "Student") {
 var MarkTable = from p in MainDB.classTable
                        group p by new { p.Student} into g
                        select new AllMarks
                             {
                                 Column = g.Key.fil,
                                 Marks = g.Sum(f => f.Mark)
                             };

    }
 else if (filter == "Teacher") {
   var MarkTable = from p in MainDB.classTable
                        group p by new { p.Teacher} into g
                        select new AllMarks
                             {
                                 Column = g.Key.fil,
                                 Marks = g.Sum(f => f.Mark)
                             };
}
 else if (filter == "Subject") {
    var MarkTable = from p in MainDB.classTable
                        group p by new { p.Subject} into g
                        select new AllMarks
                             {
                                 Column = g.Key.fil,
                                 Marks = g.Sum(f => f.Mark)
                             };
}
}
```

Comment: This would work, but not what I wanted. I want to use variable jus to have the code readability and to make it simple instead of writing if condition for huge number of filter criteria that I have.